# header nav links menu changes slightly between different pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying out to build my own website from scratch after learning about Bootstrap. I use classes like `nav navbar-nav` from Bootstrap to build my menu links that go horizontally. For example,

```
Home About Expertise Contact
```

I've noticed that after creating the second page called `About-me.html` using the same header (I saved the header in a separate file called `header.html` and called it via jQuery script in my About-me.html page), the linked menu items on the list change slightly in terms of the width of each boxes like below

```
Home About Expertise Contact (in comparison with the above example)
```

It's not that worse as I showed you but you can notice it at least with a bare eye. If I clicked the "back arrow" button on the browser to go back to my `index.html` page and clicked the next arrow button, I saw there was a slightly visible discrepancy between the two pages in regard to the top menu links navigation bar. I don't think this is normal but please correct me.

I hope I haven't confused you with the explanation of my problem.

Thank you very much

Comment: We would at least need to see an example of your HTML and CSS to be able to help you, better yet an example of the issue in http://jsfiddle.net. It sounds like you have some added whitespace, or differing CSS styles between the pages.

Comment: View the source and compare the output. (Post here if it differs and you still don't know the solution). With this little information it's hard to say whats causing this.